# How to convert this JSON to a datatable?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asynchronous, json.net

```
[
    [
        "<div id=\"status\" style=\"width:20px; height:20px; \" class=\"circle red\"></div>",
        "<a runat=\"server\" id=\"link0\" href=\"MachineDetails.aspx?PageName=PCsByLocation.aspx&MachineName=AUBDW012\">AUBDW012</>",
        "Dye, Paul",
        "",
        "AsiaPacific / Australia / BrisbaneDistribution",
        "<div id=\"divonoffswitch\" class=\"onoffswitch\"><input type=\"checkbox\"  name=\"onoffswitch\" onclick=\"javascript:hidedialoglabels();updateReasontext();spinnerOn();UpdateSpinner();__doPostBack('ContentPlaceHolder1_ucnBindSearchGrid_updReason','16800167:Auto-restart:'+this.checked+':AUBDW012:ContentPlaceHolder1_ucnBindSearchGrid_updValidation:myonoffswitch0')\" class=\"onoffswitch-checkbox\" id=\"myonoffswitch0\"  checked=\"checked\"  /><label class=\"onoffswitch-label\" for=\"myonoffswitch0\"> <span class=\"onoffswitch-inner\" ></span><span class=\"onoffswitch-switch\" ></span></label></div>",
        " <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"chkSelect0\" > "
    ],
    [
        "<div id=\"status\" style=\"width:20px; height:20px; \" class=\"circle red\"></div>",
        "<a runat=\"server\" id=\"link1\" href=\"MachineDetails.aspx?PageName=PCsByLocation.aspx&MachineName=P03719-2K1\">P03719-2K1</>",
        "Flint, Virginia",
        "",
        "AsiaPacific / Australia / BrisbaneDistribution",
        "<div id=\"divonoffswitch\" class=\"onoffswitch\"><input type=\"checkbox\"  name=\"onoffswitch\" onclick=\"javascript:hidedialoglabels();updateReasontext();spinnerOn();UpdateSpinner();__doPostBack('ContentPlaceHolder1_ucnBindSearchGrid_updReason','16797145:Auto-restart:'+this.checked+':P03719-2K1:ContentPlaceHolder1_ucnBindSearchGrid_updValidation:myonoffswitch1')\" class=\"onoffswitch-checkbox\" id=\"myonoffswitch1\"  checked=\"checked\"  /><label class=\"onoffswitch-label\" for=\"myonoffswitch1\"> <span class=\"onoffswitch-inner\" ></span><span class=\"onoffswitch-switch\" ></span></label></div>",
        " <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"chkSelect1\" > "
    ]
]
```

I'm currently using this approach to convert.

```
DataTable dtValue = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( outputJson, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

But when I execute the code I get the following exception. Please advise.

**Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object.**

Total JSON

```
  {
        "sEcho": 1,
        "iTotalRecords": 16,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 16,
        "aaData": [
            [
                "<div id=\"status\" style=\"width:20px; height:20px; \" class=\"circle red\"></div>",
                "<a runat=\"server\" id=\"link0\" href=\"MachineDetails.aspx?PageName=PCsByLocation.aspx&MachineName=AUBDW012\">AUBDW012</>",
                "Dye, Paul",
                "",
                "AsiaPacific / Australia / BrisbaneDistribution",
                "<div id=\"divonoffswitch\" class=\"onoffswitch\"><input type=\"checkbox\"  name=\"onoffswitch\" onclick=\"javascript:hidedialoglabels();updateReasontext();spinnerOn();UpdateSpinner();__doPostBack('ContentPlaceHolder1_ucnBindSearchGrid_updReason','16800167:Auto-restart:'+this.checked+':AUBDW012:ContentPlaceHolder1_ucnBindSearchGrid_updValidation:myonoffswitch0')\" class=\"onoffswitch-checkbox\" id=\"myonoffswitch0\"  checked=\"checked\"  /><label class=\"onoffswitch-label\" for=\"myonoffswitch0\"> <span class=\"onoffswitch-inner\" ></span><span class=\"onoffswitch-switch\" ></span></label></div>",
                " <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"chkSelect0\" > "
            ],
            [
                "<div id=\"status\" style=\"width:20px; height:20px; \" class=\"circle red\"></div>",
                "<a runat=\"server\" id=\"link1\" href=\"MachineDetails.aspx?PageName=PCsByLocation.aspx&MachineName=P03719-2K1\">P03719-2K1</>",
                "Flint, Virginia",
                "",
                "AsiaPacific / Australia / BrisbaneDistribution",
                "<div id=\"divonoffswitch\" class=\"onoffswitch\"><input type=\"checkbox\"  name=\"onoffswitch\" onclick=\"javascript:hidedialoglabels();updateReasontext();spinnerOn();UpdateSpinner();__doPostBack('ContentPlaceHolder1_ucnBindSearchGrid_updReason','16797145:Auto-restart:'+this.checked+':P03719-2K1:ContentPlaceHolder1_ucnBindSearchGrid_updValidation:myonoffswitch1')\" class=\"onoffswitch-checkbox\" id=\"myonoffswitch1\"  checked=\"checked\"  /><label class=\"onoffswitch-label\" for=\"myonoffswitch1\"> <span class=\"onoffswitch-inner\" ></span><span class=\"onoffswitch-switch\" ></span></label></div>",
                " <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"chkSelect1\" > "
            ]
                ]}
```

Comment: That's not JSON, that's just an array of arrays of strings. Secondly, it's not in the correct format to be deserialized into a `DataTable`. You should have an array of objects instead, e.g. `[{ "prop1": "value1"}, { "prop2": "value2" }, ...]`. The `prop` fields are the column names, and the `value` fields are the column values.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ basically it's a json... some kind of weird... but it's valid json.

Comment: Instead of string arrays you can also use `List<T>` like this: `var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<string>>>(outputJson);`

Comment: @stefankmitph: I know I'm probably taking it a bit too literally here, since I know the code is probably a string and is assigned to `outputJson`, but JSON is a notation, a `string`, and the above is presented as a literal JS array.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ you're absolutely right.

Comment: @Sashank: What's the value in having your data in `DataTable` format? Are you presenting it in a grid in a UI, or are you looking to convert from a `DataTable` to something else? Perhaps one of the others' suggestions of deserializing your JSON into a collection of collections of strings would work better for you.

Comment: I want to present it in a grid. Yea I agree that its not an actual JSON but I am using server side processing @Jquery Datatables plugin. So this is actually a part of JSON object.
The JSON object would look like this
Look in the question description.

Comment: @SashankBandhakavi What you have posted now is NOT valid JSON.

Comment: @DavidG I apologize. I have updated the right JSON.

Comment: @DavidG can you also answer to my other question about asp.net and ajax.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899839/grid-views-rows-are-not-available-on-the-server-side?noredirect=1#comment49842057_30899839

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Json string you presented isn't a deserialised `DataTable` so you can't convert it into that object type directly. Not really sure if you absolutely need for this to be a `DataTable`, but if you do then here is a way.

You can first get it into an array of string arrays like this:

```
var data = (string[][])JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(string[][])));
```

Now you can construct your data table from this array. First create a `DataTable` with the columns you need (no idea what exactly you need so I'll name them Col1 to Col7):

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Col1");
dt.Columns.Add("Col2");
dt.Columns.Add("Col3");
dt.Columns.Add("Col4");
dt.Columns.Add("Col5");
dt.Columns.Add("Col6");
dt.Columns.Add("Col7");
```

Now add each of the items from the parsed array into your table:

```
Array.ForEach(data, r => 
    {
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        row.ItemArray = r;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
);
```

## EDIT

Since you have now provided the full Json, you can create a model to store the data, something like this:

```
public class DataObject
{
    public int sEcho { get; set; }
    public int iTotalRecords { get; set; }
    public int iTotalDisplayRecords { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> aaData { get; set; }
}
```

And you can deserialise into this type like this:

```
var data = (DataObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataObject)));
```